# arXiv or MathSciNet statistics by MSC classes and time

Tags: publications, arxiv, statistics

I suppose I'm not the first person who came across this idea. I would like to compare math branches by means of numbers of articles published. I have access to two large math article indices: AMS' MathSciNet and arXiv.

My question is: Is it possible (in either of them) to get the information *how many articles were published with a given MSC class, year by year*?

Comment: For the arxiv, all it takes is some facility with scripting and web scraping. the data is all there.

Comment: @Suresh I know it _is_ there, but it's rather difficult to retrieve it, moreover, officially frowned upon by arXiv if I understood things correctly :-/

Comment: really ? they provide the stats themselves (on a per-year basis aggregated across subjects). And I doubt they'd object to a slow web crawl over the year-by-year pages (after which you can parse locally). In particular, they have an explicit policy on how to access article meta data (which is all you need): http://arxiv.org/help/oa/index

Answer (score 2):

If you use R, you can use [this script](https://github.com/johnros/scaping_arxiv) I wrote for scraping ArXiv metadata.